# if instead of else

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a simple question: I have got two functions. Both of them use

```
if(...) {expression}
if(...) {expression}
if(...) {expression}
```

instead of

```
if(...) {expression}
else{
      if(...) {expression}
      else {expression}
}
```

But only the one of both works.

The first one works perfectly:

```
test.1 <- function (y) {
 if(y == 1){z <- 10}
 if(y == 2){z <- 20}
 if(y == 5){z <- 50}

 return(z)
}
```

The second one does not work:

```
df.1 <- data.frame(A = 1:3)
df.2 <- data.frame(A = 4:6)
df.3 <- data.frame(A = 7:9)

 test.2 <- function (num) {
  x <- with(if(num == 1){df.1} 
            if(num == 2){df.2}
            if(num == 3){df.3}, {sum(A)})
return(x)
}
```

I need to use the if else expressions in order to get the second function work:

```
test.2 <- function (num) {
  x <- with(if(num == 1){df.1} 
            else {if(num == 2){df.2}
                  else {df.3}
                  }, {sum(A)})
  return(x)
}
```

I really do not understand why this multiple if statement work in the first case but not in the second one!??

Comment: Did you trie taking the if's out of the x <- with part.

So the if's set a variable that you then use in the x <- with part?

Comment: Yes I already tried it. It works but in my real code the with(...) part has 200 lines of code, which means that if I do it this way I get 600 lines of code instead of 200. This is why I would like to insert the if's on the right places inside with().

Comment: The fundamental problem is that your second function is not anything resembling proper R syntax.  You're essentially asking it for `ith(if(num == 1){df.1}if(num == 2){df.2}if(num == 3){df.3}, {sum(A)})` i.e. two arguments to with(), which is just garbage in this context.  Use `switch` instead.  `if` is not designed to return a value anyway, so your data.frames in the {} will print rather than getting assigned to `x` as far as I can think of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second example doesn't work because the first argument to `with` is supposed to be "an environment, a list, a data frame, or an integer as in `sys.call`" (see the Arguments section `?with`).

You can avoid the "unexpected end of line" error by wrapping the if statements in curly brackets:

```
test.2 <- function (num) {
  x <- with({if(num == 1)df.1 
             if(num == 2)df.2
             if(num == 3)df.3}, {sum(A)})
  return(x)
}
```

But this still won't work because you have 3 expressions inside the brackets and only the last evaluated expression will be returned.  Well, it will work if `num==3`... but we can do better.  You could use `switch` here instead:

```
test.2 <- function (num) {
  with(switch(num, df.1, df.2, df.3), sum(A))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off using `switch`:

```
test.2 <- function(num){
 x <- with(switch(num,df.1,df.2,df.3),{sum(A)})
 return(x)
}


test.2(1)
[1] 6
test.2(2)
[1] 15
test.2(3)
[1] 24
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems: Firstly, `with` expects a single expression (that evaulates to a data.frame or environment) in its first argument.  You can fix that by wrapping those `if` statements in curly braces to make it a single expression.

```
test.2 <- function (num) {
  x <- with(
    {
      if(num == 1){df.1} 
      if(num == 2){df.2}
      if(num == 3){df.3}
    }, 
    sum(A)
  )
  return(x)
}
```

The second problem is that you aren't returning from the expression after you find a match.  So when `num` is 1, the first if condition is met and the `df.1` is returned.  But then the next `if` expression is evaulated, and since `num` isn't 2, `NULL` is returned.  Similarly, the third `if` expression returns `NULL`.  Since that is the last expression in the block, that's what gets returned.  You effectively have

```
with(NULL, sum(A))
```

which is the same as simply `sum(A)`, which throws an error because `A` doesn't exist.

You could make another fix like

```
test.2 <- function (num) {
  x <- with(
    {
      if(num == 1)return(df.1) 
      if(num == 2)return(df.2)
      if(num == 3)return(df.3)
    }, 
    sum(A)
  )
  return(x)
}
```

(this works when `num` is 1, 2 or 3 ) but you are much better off using `switch` instead, like James suggests.

---

If all your data frames are consistently named, as in the example, then there's an even better solution than using `switch`.  Use `paste` to get the variable name, then call `get`.

```
test.3 <- function(num) with(get(paste("df", num, sep = ".")), sum(A))
test.3(1) #6
test.3(2) #15
test.3(3) #24
```

Answer (score 0):

it's possible that all three `expression`s execute.

```
if(...) {expression} 
if(...) {expression} 
if(...) {expression}
```

In below case, only one `expression` will execute.

```
if(...) {expression}  
else
{        
    if(...) {expression}        
    else 
    {
        expression
    }
}
```

Comment: In general you are rigth. This is not the problem though. If you try to run the code I posted above (test.2), you will see that R comes up with an error like "unexpected end of line".

Comment: Oh .. it's R. it's not my cup of tea at present.